# prepareForSegue not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios

I have set up a view in which a user can pick a photo and then use it as their profile picture. Once they picked the image a UIImageView is supposed to be updated. I use the prepareForSegue method in order to pass the information on to the view controller which contains the image view. However, the image never gets updated when I pass something forwards.
This is my code:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UploadSuccessSegue"]) {  
       UploadSuccessViewController *usv = (UploadSuccessViewController *)  
       [segue destinationViewController];  
       usv.bookView.image = self.uploadedImage.image;
    }
  }
```

Any help help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a UIImage @property on UploadSuccessViewController, set the UIImage on prepareForSegue, then on viewDidLoad of UploadSuccessViewController set the image on UIImaveView

Comment: @GTSouza you should post answer so Tim can accept it. I am going to clarify, but I hope you get the credit for answering first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, GTSouza hit the nail on the head. So you want to create a property to hold your `UIImage` reference in `UploadSuccessViewController.h`, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IUImage *bookImage;
```

then your prepareForSegue can populate it:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UploadSuccessSegue"]) {  
        UploadSuccessViewController *usv = [segue destinationViewController];  
        usv.bookImage = self.uploadedImage.image;
    }
}
```

Then the `UploadSuccessViewController` `viewDidLoad` can use it:

```
self.bookView.image = self.bookImage;
```

Comment: Sounds good. That worked out quite well. Thanks for the help.